# Extending Google Appstats

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

After watching [Guido's Google IO talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvp7CuBWVgA) and hearing the mention that it can be extended (thus providing an instrumentation mechanism for recording your own events) I am still at a loss on how this would be done.

The functions are all for handling RPC and not simply start/stop calls an expensive function (or wrapper) can make.

Has anyone extended the library, more to the point in a safe manner that doesn't require overriding the original?

Comment: Is there something you actually want to do with it that requires an extension?

Comment: Record the length of time a CPU intensive tasks takes and report it under AppStats (important when using the python27 runtime and threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was referring to the ability to record custom events.  A simple example is:

```
from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
recording.recorder.record_custom_event('hello', 'data')
```

Note that you should really check whether recorder is not None before calling its record_custom_event() method.

Comment: PS. It's Appstats, not AppStats.

Comment: Changing the question title now ;-)

Comment: Is this also possible in the Java version of Appstats?

Comment: @gvanrossum I think I found a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6448) in the recorder related to when PATH_INFO and SCRIPT_NAME are passed as unicode strings.

Comment: is it possible to extend Appstats also in Java? I didn't find anything in the web

Comment: Please start a new question instead of tacking a comment onto an old one.

Comment: I found I had to use the recorder_proxy rather than the recorder.